# magento add item and redirect to one page checkout in url

Tags: magento

I have seen answers that are close to what I am looking for.  I want to add a product to the cart and also redirect to one page checkout in one single link tag from an email.

So far i have:

http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/20759/qty/1/

This successfully adds item to the cart, but does not re-direct to one page checkout. Is there any easy solution to add something to the url?

Ideally something like this?

http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/20759/qty/1/"one-page-checkout-link"

Thanks everyone!

Comment: use this of way: http://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/magento-redirect-to-checkout-after-add-to-cart/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks David!  You pointed me in the right direction.  here is what did the trick:

http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/20759/qty/1/?return_url=http://www.example.com/checkout/onepage/

If I had a higher rep I would vote you up.....

Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

If you add the parameter 'return_url' then this will work:

```
?return_url=http://magento.localhost/checkout/onepage/
```

It will need to be url encoded and also will be checked with the function `_isUrlInternal` as you cannot redirect to external urls.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `form_key` for latest versions of magento.

For eg., http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/20759/qty/1/form_key/Nf9kXuUu89DLTeT7/?return_url=http://www.example.com/checkout/onepage/

Now the product will be add to cart in magento.

Note: Note the `form_key` in url

You can get the form key by using the below code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
```